# Critical: Remap power key on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, remapping

Water accidentally spilled on my laptop, now my power key does not work.

Im really afraid that it won't turn on once I turn it off.

Can I remap this key to something else? I tried following [Remap Power Off key in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861118/remap-power-off-key-in-ubuntu-16-04) but it didnt have a solution and I didnt want to screw up my com.

Any assistance is really really appreciated! :)

Comment: Is this genuine? If you spilled water over your laptop, the first thing you should do is turn it off! Not ask a question here.

Comment: @SamuelSantana Ofcourse its genuine why would I waste anyones time including my own? Yeah i know that but only one button isn't working, my laptop is critical I cant afford it to die on me now. So I thought just dont turn it off and see if theres a solution

Comment: I'd recommend you do turn it off. Open your computer, check the motherboard for any damage. Clean it with some isopropyl alcohol and let it dry... go to sleep. Check again if it works tomorrow. If not, get some professional help.

If you have a phone, you can use it to access the stack exchange sites, so that you can follow whatever happens here. Although I don't think we can provide much help, since your problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, No.  When the computer is not on, there is no software running to decide what to do with the key.  The power key has to be hard wired to power on the machine.

Comment: This. --^. Also, if it's just a bad button, you could buy a new one on EBay.

Comment: Its a laptop power button. How can i test if it's just the button? I dont think I can remove the keyboard. Is it safe to open it up? I'm thinking of just never shutting the laptop down instead. Would that work? I cant afford to not have a working laptop now